# PHP Mail HTML Comment Form Variables

Tags: php, html, forms, variables, mailer

Can you provide the proper syntax to pass the html form variables to php mailer?

The php is:

```
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$to      = 'sssff@gmail.com';
$subject = 'From Website';
$message = $comment;
$headers = 'From: $email';

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

$message needs to contain the contents of $comment

$headers needs to display the contents of $email as return address

Can anyone help me with the proper syntax? Thank you

## EDIT

To clarify, the email   i receive from the php mailer does not contain the from address contained by $email, nor does the message contain the comments from $comment.

The email is sent fine, but does not contain those crucial elements.

If you'd like to look at the form it is:

```
<form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="POST" action="">
     <label for="cname">Name</label>
     <input id="cname" type="text" name="name" size="60" class="required" minlength="2" />

     <label for="cemail">E-Mail</label>
     <input id="cemail" type="text" name="email" size="60"  class="required email" />

     <label for="curl">URL</label>
     <input id="curl" type="text" name="url" size="60"  class="url" value="" />

     <label for="ccomment">Your comment</label>
     <textarea id="ccomment" type="text" name="comment" cols="72" rows="8"  class="required"></textarea>
     <div id="button2"><input class="submit" id="submit_btn" type="submit" value="Send Email"/></div>
</form>
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Looks okay to me. What is the problem, what doesn't work? Of course, $email should be a valid sender address on the domain you're sending from... if it's not, use `Reply-to` instead

Comment: And your exact problem is? While verbose, there's nothing really wrong with that code

Comment: I guess you are having error running it on localhost ..... SMTP not installed :) as far as the code ok ... pretty ok

Comment: I dont know why but the email I receive from the php mailer does not have a return to address or a subject. Something is wrong with $comment and $email

Comment: Edited the question to show more details. Thanks for all contributions.

Answer (score 1):

```
$headers = 'From: $email';
           ^---         ^---
```

should be `"` instead. Single quoted strings do not interpolate variables, so you're using a literal `$email` as your From address, not `someone@example.com`.

Comment: I dont know why but for some reason the email I receive does not contain a from address even when one is entered into the form. Also the comment field does not get passed.

Answer (score -1):

```
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$to = "$email";

$from = 'sender email';
$subject = 'message subject';
//Begin HTML Email Message
$message = "$comment";
//end of message
$headers  = "From: $from\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: Not quite sure why but the email I receive does not contain the from address of the sender ($email) or the message ($comment). Any ideas thanks